# Creating a video from images using OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv

My code:

```
video = cv2.VideoWriter(name, 0, 1, size)

for image in frames:
    video.write(image)

video.release()
```

`name` is a string describing the filename, size is `(360, 640)` and frames is a list containing all the images (ndarrays with all the color values). When I try to run this code, it returns

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'image'
```

What does that mean and how do I fix this error?

Edit:
My code is now:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
video = cv2.VideoWriter('mosaic.avi', fourcc, 30, size)

for image in frames:
    video.write(np.float32(image))

video.release()
```

It does not return any errors, however the video is corrupted.

Comment: The error you are getting is because it is not the right form. cv2.Umat() is functionally equivalent to np.float32()

Comment: @AvinashKoshal np.float32() did fix it, however the file it outputs is now corrupted. Any ideas why? My new code is in my question.

Comment: Did you tried the Cv2.UMat() function
 
`video = cv2.VideoWriter(name, 0, 1, size)

for image in frames:
    video.write(cv2.UMat(image))

video.release()`
Try this

Comment: syntax is not displaying correctly here 
Use the first code from my below given answer

Answer (score 0):

UMat is a part of the Transparent API (TAPI) than help to write one code for the CPU and OpenCL implementations.
You can correct this error by following methods :

```
video = cv2.VideoWriter(name, 0, 1, size)

for image in frames:
    video.write(cv2.UMat(image))

video.release()
```

Or

```
Import numpy as np
video = cv2.VideoWriter(name, 0, 1, size)

for image in frames:
    image = np.array(image)
    video.write(image)

video.release()
```

Comment: Using cv2.UMat returns the error `TypeError: UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2)` and the second method returns the same error as in my question